# What exactly is the interaction that blocked Juno's data downlink near solar conjunction?

Tags: jupiter, juno, deep-space-network, data-transmission, skyfield

According to Space.com's article [Juno Phones Home: Jupiter Probe Reconnects with Earth After 8th Flyby](https://www.space.com/38668-juno-8th-jupiter-science-flyby-success.html), Juno's recent close flyby of Jupiter and data collection happened while Jupiter was too close to the Sun as seen from Earth for the data to be reliably received by the Deep Space Network.

Here is a GIF made from some [SOHO LASCO C3](https://sohodata.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/data_query) images; you can see Jupiter disappear behind the central occultation disk that protects each SOHO imager from the Sun. (Incidentally, that's Comet 96P on the right; see the NASA Goddard feature [Return of the Comet: 96P Spotted by ESA, NASA Satellites](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2017/return-of-the-comet-96p-spotted-by-esa-nasa-satellites).)

[image]

> Solar conjunctions of Jupiter — when Earth's and Jupiter's orbits take the planets on opposite sides of the sun — mean that a spacecraft orbiting Jupiter can't transmit to Earth without the [charged particles the sun emits](https://www.space.com/22215-solar-wind.html) corrupting the probe's signal. The last solar conjunction of Jupiter was in August 2015, before Juno had arrived at Jupiter, and the next will be in November 2018, according to [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/news.php?id=20181126_12_100).

Of course the article is wrong, and the previous conjunction would have been in 2016.

I've plotted the angles below; it looks like about 1.5 degrees is too close, but 4 degrees is OK. Those correspond to a closest approach of the line-of sight to the surface of the Sun of 3 vs 10 million kilometers.

**Question:** Is this a simple plasma density effect? When the line-of-sight passes too close to the Sun the cut-off frequency drops below that used by the spacectraft for downlink? Is the density of the solar wind at this distance quantitatively high enough to become opaque at this frequency? Or is the problem more complicated, and perhaps also involves too much dispersion? Or perhaps a geometrical problem; it's too hard to point so close to the Sun without equipment damage, or even a radio interference problem; there is too much spillover of radio noise from the Sun and the weak spacecraft signal can not be separated well enough to allow for a high-bandwidth downlink?

**note:** I'm looking for some level of explanation, and not just an answer that says "Because of interference from the Sun." Thanks!

---

Plot of calculated positions and separation using the python package [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api.html). I'm not sure of the exact time of the beginning of successful downlink, so I've just added seven days to the time of flyby (estimated from [JPL's Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi).)

Tiny dots are spaced at 1 day intervals, medium-sized red dot on the left is the moment of flyby, large-sized green dot near the right is roughly the time of successful downlink.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skyfield.api import Loader  # http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/

degs = 180./np.pi

load = Loader('~/Documents/SkyData')
data = load('de421.bsp')
ts   = load.timescale()
sun, earth, jupiter = data['sun'], data['earth'], data['jupiter barycenter']

ddays = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)  # ten days by 0.1 day steps

times = ts.utc(2017, 10, 24+ddays, 17, 44) # with respect to 17:44 UTC, October 24th, 2017

observations = [earth.at(times).observe(thing) for thing in sun, jupiter]
separation   = degs*observations[1].separation_from(observations[0]).radians

if True:
    fig = plt.figure()

    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

    for obs in observations:
        RAdegs, Decdegs = [degs*thing.radians for thing in obs.radec()[:2]]
        ax1.plot(RAdegs, Decdegs)
        ax1.plot(RAdegs[::10],  Decdegs[::10],  '.k'                 )
        ax1.plot(RAdegs[:1],    Decdegs[:1],    'or', markersize =  8)
        ax1.plot(RAdegs[70:71], Decdegs[70:71], 'og', markersize = 12)

    ax1.set_xlim(208, 220)
    ax1.set_ylim(-16, -10)
    ax1.set_aspect(1.0) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/18576329/3904031
    ax1.set_xlabel('RA (degs)')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Dec (degs)')
    ax1.set_title('Sun and Jupiter observed from Earth geocenter, start 2017-10-24, 17:44 UTC')
    ax1.text(212, -11, 'Sun')
    ax1.text(212, -14, 'Jupiter')

    ax2  = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

    ax2.plot(ddays, separation)
    ax2.plot(ddays[:1],    separation[:1],    'or', markersize =  8)
    ax2.plot(ddays[70:71], separation[70:71], 'og', markersize = 12)
    ax2.set_xlim(-0.5, None)
    ax2.set_ylim(0, None)
    ax2.set_xlabel('days since flyby')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Jupiter/Sun separation (degs)')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe someone can find a reference, but I always thought it was because: 1) the Sun is noisy at the frequency used in communications, so you cannot hear the signal above the noise, 2) it's not good to point a parabolic "reflector" at the Sun, otherwise you will burn up the receiver situated at the focus.

Comment: @JohnHoltz I believe (though haven't verified that) the dishes surface is not "shiny" or specular to visible or IR sunlight, so it won't concentrate or focus heat on the waveguides even when pointed directly at the Sun. You can see some photos of the DSN's 70 meter dish at Goldstone in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21269/12102). The optics of the dishes are pretty good, and generally can reject radio sources much much less than 1 degree away, looking for a reference for this.

Comment: "The first solar radar echoes were detected by a research group at Stanford University in 1959." [see](http://www.df5ai.net/ArticlesDL/SolarRadar/SolarRadar.html). If radar signals are reflected, data transmission signals may be blocked if the Sun is between transmitter and receiver.

Comment: @Uwe but the problem discussed here is when the line of sight passes *near the Sun* (of order 1 to 4 degrees) but *not necessarily through the Sun*. Of course I understand that the signals can not go directly through the sun!

Comment: @uhoh: If the Sun is not in direct line of sight, but still within a [Fresnel zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_zone), data transmission may be still influenced. What about calculating the Fresnel zones for the transmission path between Juno and Earth and compare them with the location of the Sun?

Comment: Some links about the electromagnetic emission of the Sun in the GHz range: [1](http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/~hamish/cesra/Costas_CESRA_QuietSun.pdf), [2](http://www2.mps.mpg.de/meetings/ccmag/dokumente/presentations/A.04.01.pdf), [3](https://www.primalucelab.com/radioastronomy/blog/sole-radio-sun), [4](https://hesperia.gsfc.nasa.gov/summerschool/lectures/bastian/Solar_Radio_Emission.pdf),

Comment: Some more links: [5](https://www.haystack.mit.edu/workshop/Radio-Stars/presentations/White_RadioStars.pdf), [6](http://www.astro.gla.ac.uk/wp-content/uploads/Kontar_intro_radio_emission.pdf), [7](http://planeterrella.osug.fr/IMG/pdf/stellar_emissions.pdf), [8](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/edu/nycri/research/files/2004/04-MEC1.ppt)  

Very scientific stuff with a lot of mathematics and physics.

Comment: Another link [SOLAR RADIO INTERFERENCE TO SATELLITE DOWNLINKS](http://www.spaceacademy.net.au/spacelink/solrfi/solrfi.htm)

Comment: @Uwe still I am wondering if the problem is 1. interference received by DSN because of the small angular separation (that would be addressed by your links), or 2. if the signal passing physically through the plasma close to the sun is disrupted by the plasma, or 3. if the DSN telescopes simply can not point so close to the Sun without thermal damage.

Comment: @Uwe I've added a bounty... You've mentioned many helpful links, but this question is about the Deep Space Network's capability, so it needs more than a general hypothetical answer. Have you found anything about DSN's capability specifically?

Comment: You may be interested in [the DSN Link Design Handbook](https://evt.grc.nasa.gov/rfp-industry-briefing-2016/wp-content/blogs.dir/52/files/sites/10/Deep-Space-Network-Telecommunications-Link-Design-Handbook-810-005.pdf), module 105.

Comment: @TonioElGringo thanks! I can see some helpful plots in the vicinity of page 200 of the PDF, in section *105 Atmospheric and Environmental Effects*

Comment: @TonioElGringo I've added a bounty; consider posting an answer?

Comment: We recently had to transfer the Wind spacecraft from a Lissajous to halo orbit about L1 because the z-component of the former would have caused Wind to fall into the solar exclusion zone or SEZ (i.e., the region about the Sun regarding your question).  It's a signal-to-noise ratio issue.  The Sun is radio loud, so the very weak signal received from far away spacecraft cannot compete.  Generally for Wind, the SEZ is at about ~1.5-1.8 degrees, depending on season and which ground station is used.  I imagine Juno is similar or larger.

Comment: @honeste_vivere it's so nice to see your great answers and informative comments as always! This reminds me that you'd mentioned Wind here as well: [Why is DSCOVR in a Lissajous orbit? Wouldn't a halo orbit completely avoid the Sun exclusion zone?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31504/12102) From DESCANSO reading and the answer here, the signal problems for spacecraft that go *behind* the Sun start with the distortion (path/phase shifts and amplitude fading) due to the inhomogeneous electron density of solar wind first, even when dishes can still spatially separate the signals from the Sun's

Comment: @uhoh - That's interesting, I hadn't thought of that.  Though phase shifts due to density gradients along a single line of sight should be symmetric if the looking through a spherically symmetric atmosphere, right?  I suppose near the sun, even ~1% density fluctuations are comparatively huge to the rest of the transit path of the signal though... Hmm...

Comment: @honeste_vivere short wave AM radio listeners are familiar with just how funky signals can sound when *reflecting* from inhomogeneous electron density distributions. In addition to overall fading when multipath signals interfere destructively, each different frequency in the sidebands experiences phase shifts and fading differently. Some examples: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKUsl7PZNr4), [2](https://youtu.be/RAOw9Xu-hqs?t=886), [3](https://youtu.be/hFRYKDF2kxs?t=355) though the last one also has some interference effects.

Comment: @honeste_vivere *Transmission through* inhomogeneities in the spatially far larger though far lower electron density solar wind will have [multipath effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_propagation) as well. For AM radio short wave listening (e.g. especially the 2nd YouTube link at it's current time), the frequency-dependent multipath interference sounds a bit like [flanging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanging).

Comment: more mulipath effects here: https://youtu.be/PKUsl7PZNr4?t=66

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This article claims that it's the charged particles emitted by the sun that actually block communication with Juno. https://www.space.com/38668-juno-8th-jupiter-science-flyby-success.html  This article about Mars conjunction cites the same physics and points out more succinctly that it's the command uplink that operators are worried about corrupting. https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7485

From talking to the payload operations folks at Malin Space Science Systems where I work, I can tell you that many of the missions they support including Juno and the Mars rovers, will attempt to downlink data during times apart from the very middle of conjunction, and that will result in varying degrees of data corruption requiring packet retransmission once commanding is re-established.  So I would argue that the real issue is that the uplink packet loss rate becomes too high and it's too much trouble to retransmit so much of the uplink commands once the RF noise floor goes too high for the spacecraft receiver.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for finding this long-lost question and posting an authoritative and well-sourced answer!